# License key generation after purchase with django

Tags: python, django

Hi I was wondering how its possible with django to generate a license key once someone has made a purchase on my site, I'm still trying to learn the framework and understand how it works. I'm guessing it would be something to do with views.py as it would be a request but as I said i'm only just learning the basic fundamentals as of right now and I've done some research and I cant seem to find much.

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect? We will not design the whole license system for you. You have to ask a more specific question and present what you have tried so far.

Comment: Once a user becomes verified for example, generate a license key (random characters) and adds it automatically to the database. How would I go about doing this? It would be making a function in the views.py right? Or would I need to make another app for this to work.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.